# Avoiding NullPointerException by using ConnectivityManager and NetworkInfo

Tags: android, networking, wifi, toast, connectivity

In my application I'm querying a database via the use of a PHP script. Currently, it gets the information as soon as the app comes up on the screen. However, if you don't have an internet connection it returns a NullPointerException because it's not getting any data. I've since updated my code with a ConnectivityManager and NetworkInfo that displays a toast if the user is not connected to either their network or to a WiFi. The problem is it's skipping this and just executing the rest of the code like normal.

```
public class Shc_BalloonSat_Activity extends Activity
{
int historyCountFromUser;
httpAPI api;
mapAPI map;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.#####");
DecimalFormat decimalf = new DecimalFormat("##.######");
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor prefEditor;
String lastpacketsPHP;

// User to determine how many packet the user would like to see.
int userDefinedCount = 5;

/*
 *  Called when the activity is first created. 
*/

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String returned = "";
    lastpacketsPHP = "";
    pref = getSharedPreferences("shared_prefs", 0);
    prefEditor = pref.edit();
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "/* PHP file url goes here */");
    prefEditor.commit();       

    if(!isNetworkConnected(this))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please connect to the internet to access the full functionality of this app.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else
    {
         api = new httpAPI(this);
         map = new mapAPI(this);

        try
        {
            returned = api.getData();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TextView infoTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.info);
        infoTV.setText(returned);
        assignInfoToInfoTextView();
        assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
    }

}

public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }

    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Update (LogCat error message):

```
02-19 13:55:19.450: E/log_tag(443): Error in HTTP connection: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: space.uah.edu:80
02-19 13:55:19.450: E/log_tag(443): Error converting result:     java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 13:55:19.450: E/log_tag(443): Error in HTTP connection: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: space.uah.edu:80
02-19 13:55:19.450: E/log_tag(443): Error converting result: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 13:55:19.450: E/AndroidRuntime(443): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{shc_BalloonSat.namespace/shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.util.Log.println(Native Method)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:208)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.assignInfoToInfoTextView(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:173)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at shc_BalloonSat.namespace.Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.onCreate(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity.java:75)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-19 13:55:19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
02-19 13:55 :19.473: E/AndroidRuntime(443):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your connection check logic working fine, make it as, if/else. If not connected show toast, else continue with logic.

```
     if(!isNetworkConnected(this))         {     
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please connect to the internet to access the full functionality of this app.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
       }
else
    {          
    TextView infoTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.info);     
    infoTV.setText(returned);      
    assignInfoToInfoTextView();     
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView(); 
    }
```

Comment: I did that. If you'll notice in my code I got the same if statement twice. It's because I moved it up to the top and forgot to remove the original. The top one has an else statement.

Comment: are you seeing Toast or not seeing anything? If not getting toast, may be do complete uninstall and do install.

Comment: I'm not seeing the toast at all. The screen is black and it just sits there for a min then it crashes. I tried uninstalling it and then re-installing it and I still get the problem.

Comment: can you post logcat message? Have you added required permissions?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the original post with the LogCat message. Yes, I have.

Comment: ahh! I should have asked logcat initially, it is java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: space.uah.edu:80 , are you sure you have space.uah.edu host which allows connection on port 80? Shouldn't it be 8080? Remember this is not related to internet connection. You have given a host/port url which is wrong. Try to ping same url from browser and see you are able to access it or not.

Comment: Yes I have access to it. When I go to the link it displays the data I want in the browser.

Comment: Did you try hardcoding the url instead of getting from preferences? I would try hardcode url. I am sure something messed with URL you are using.

Comment: I think you might be missing the problem. It should not be trying to go to that link. I'm doing all this when I'm not connected to the network or to a Wifi network. It should be displaying the toast message. The only time it should try to go to that link is when the phone is on some type of network connection.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7925/discussion-between-thinksteep-and-randomlyknighted)

Comment: I uninstalled the app from my phone and ran the program on it instead of the emulator and the Toast works fine. I guess the problem we were having earlier was just a problem with the emulator.